# Result pagination for bulk API with MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, rest, api, pagination

How does results pagination work for bulk API with MongoDB?

API endpoint(just for context):

```
/team/listTeamsForUsers
```

Input:

```
{
   "userIds": ["userId1", "userId2", "userId3"...],
   "options": {
       "pageSize": 10,
       "pageIndex": 0
    }
}
```

A user can be associated with multiple teams. Hence the API needs ability to paginate the results, based on `pageSize` and `pageIndex`.

Pagination is possible for single `userId` input. How do I support pagination for multiple inputs?

Example use case:
`User01` is associated to 10 teams.
`User02` is associated to 20 teams.

```
when pageSize=10 and pageIndex=0
    Teams 1-10 related to User01 should be returned.

when pageSize=10 and pageIndex=1
    Teams 1-10 related to User02 should be returned.

when pageSize=10 and pageIndex=2
    Teams 11-20 related to User02 should be returned.
```

It would be great to see examples of such implementation.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

**Assumptions:**

- I suppose a user can be a member in multiple teams and a team has multiple members. Therefore, users and teams are in a many to many relationship.
- I further assume you have a junction table that maps from userId to teamId in order to model the above relationship.

**Table structures:**

- Users table : **id | name**
- Teams table : **id | name**
- UsersTeams  : **userId | teamId**

Considering you get a list of userId as input, a SQL snippet for paging the teams associated with those users would look as follows (please note I did not test the below snippet).

```
select distinct t.name
    from team t, user u, userTeam ut
    where t.id = ut.teamId and u.id = ut.userId and u.id in (1, 2)
    order by t.name desc
    limit 0, 10;
```

- The parameters passed to `limit` are the `pageIndex*pageSize` and `(pageIndex+1)*pagSize`.
- The parameters passed to `in` are the `userIds` you get from the endpoint.

Although this approach is easy to understand and implement, it does not have the best performance. Please see https://www.xarg.org/2011/10/optimized-pagination-using-mysql/ for paging optimizations for MySQL (although you probably can translate most of that to any SQL database).

Comment: Thanks alexrolea. I'm more concerned about the response here. If limit =10 and the first userId has 10 teams associated, the response limit is reached. How would the second userId be processed?

Comment: If there will be 33 distinct teams for user1 and user2, the first 10 will be returned for `{pageIndex:0, pageSize:10}`, the 10-20 for `{pageIndex:1, pageSize:10}`, the 20-30 for for `{pageIndex:2, pageSize:10}` and the last 3 for for `{pageIndex:4, pageSize:10}`. This is ensured since we do `order by t.name desc`, which ensures a deterministic ordering between the teams. This assumes you are sending the user ids with each request, modifying only the `pageIndex` with each subsequent request.

Comment: Does that make sense?